# Change rsync port with php exec

Tags: php, ssh, rsync

With PHP, I am trying to connect to a remote server and exec an rsync command :

```
$rsync_cmd = 'rsync -P -azv -e "ssh -p 1234" /dir/file.jpg root@remoteserver2:/dir/file.jpg';

exec('sudo ssh -tt root@remoteserver1 '.$rsync_cmd.' 2>&1', $output);
```

The remote connection is working fine but then when I am including my rsync command I got a port error **"ssh: connect to host remoteserver2 port 22: Connection refused"**

The correct port to use is 1234 and this command is working fine on the Terminal (shell) but php "exec" function dont want to take it ("ssh -p 1234"), any idea ?

Comment: Are you using an SSH key? Also, just sayin', what sane person does this kind of thing with the root account?

Comment: Yes I do, if not the first step will prompt for password :) Root or not doesnt change much when you work alone and its easier for debugging in a case like that, also its a one time thing here, I just migrate some stuffs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you test it in Terminal by `ssh`ing into remoteserver1, and then executing the `rsync` command, or by executing the entire `ssh`-to-`rsync` command on one line? Because I'm pretty sure doing it in two steps will work, but one step won't. This is because when it's done as one step, the command string is parsed by the local shell (including doing quote and escape interpretation and removal) before it's passed over `ssh` to the remote shell (which then does another pass of quote and escape interpretation and removal). Those double-quotes in `"ssh -p 1234"` get parsed and removed by the local shell, so they don't have the intended effect of being parsed and applied by the remote shell.

If I'm right about the problem, the solution is pretty simple: escape the double-quotes. That way the local shell will parse and remove the escapes, and pass the double-quotes through unmolested so the remote shell can see and apply them:

```
$rsync_cmd = 'rsync -P -azv -e \"ssh -p 1234\" /dir/file.jpg root@remoteserver2:/dir/file.jpg';

exec('sudo ssh -tt root@remoteserver1 '.$rsync_cmd.' 2>&1', $output);
```

Comment: Yes it was working fine in Terminal and you were right it was the quotes, they got removed, I tried `\' \'` and `" `" but the solution was `\" \"`. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is pretty mush simple try skipping `-P` flag from the command.

```
$rsync_cmd = 'rsync -azv -e \"ssh -p 1234\" /dir/file.jpg root@remoteserver2:/dir/file.jpg';

exec('sudo ssh -tt root@remoteserver1 '.$rsync_cmd.' 2>&1', $output);
```

It will work fine with that `-P` flag it took default port for the rsync.

Comment: You are right on this but its still dont get the right one (1234), Gordon answer was right, issue came from the quote. Thanks anyway :)